# const_cast of a static member vector of objects

Tags: c++, static, constants

I'm starting to code the Djambi board game in C++. I created a class for the squares of the board, and I created a static vector of pointers to square objects to have the actual board of my game. Each square is characterised by its row and column, so that defining my board means associating to each component of the vector a square with the right coordinates. The point is that once I have defined my vector, I'd like it to be constant because I want each element of the vector to point to the same square, but how can I make it constant and then define it with a for loop? Since it's a static member I can't even define it in the class scope. Some help would be really appreciated.

```
//square.h
#include<vector>
 class square 
{
protected:
    size_t row{ 0 };
    size_t column{ 0 };
    bool occupancy{ false };
public:
    square() {  };
    square(size_t r, size_t c): row{r}, column{c} { } 
    square(size_t r, size_t c, bool occ) : row{ r }, column{ c }, occupancy{ occ } {    }
    ~square() { };
    bool & get_status() { return occupancy; };
    size_t& get_row() { return row; };
    size_t& get_column() { return column; };
    static const size_t rank{ 9 };
    static std::vector<square*> board;  
    static size_t indice(size_t r, size_t c);
    static void define_board();
};
//square.cpp
#include"square.h"
#include<string>
size_t square::indice(size_t r, size_t c) {
    size_t indice = rank * (r - 1) + c;
    return indice;
};
std::vector<square*> square::board = std::vector<square*>(81);
void square::define_board() {
    for (size_t r = 1; r <= square::rank; r++) {
        for (size_t c = 1; c < 9; c++) {
            *(board[indice(r, c)]) = square(r, c);
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize it with the value you want it to have:

```
const std::vector<square> square::board = define_board();
std::vector<square> square::define_board() {
    std::vector<square> board(81);
    for (size_t r = 1; r <= square::rank; r++) {
        for (size_t c = 1; c < 9; c++) {
            board[indice(r, c)] = square(r, c);
        }
    }
    return board;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help! It doesn't allow me to put it constant. If I add the const qualifier and initialize it how you you suggested it gives me <a member of type "const std::vector<square, std::allocator<square>>" cannot have an in-class initializer>

Comment: You have to initialize it outside of the class, as you had before.